# Exception happens when doing Solr Unit Testing

Tags: junit, solr, lucene

The following exception happens when doing Solr Unit Test, and could not google the answer, could someone help on this ?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.AssertionError: ensure your setUp() calls super.setUp() and your tearDown() calls super.tearDown()!!!
    at org.apache.lucene.util.LuceneTestCase.afterClassLuceneTestCaseJ4(LuceneTestCase.java:311)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:62)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:140)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1009)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: ensure your setUp() calls super.setUp() and your tearDown() calls super.tearDown()!!!
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:91)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:43)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.LuceneTestCase.afterClassLuceneTestCaseJ4(LuceneTestCase.java:256)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: well, does your setup() call super.setUp() and same thing with tearDown()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your unit test derives from a base class of the Lucense test framework which requires that the overridden setUp() and tearDown() are still called, i.e. calling super.setUp() or super.tearDown() in your unit test should fix this, e.g.:

```
public void setUp() {
    // your set up code
    ...
    super.setUp();
```

Answer (score -1):

Ensure you have the correct jar files and also the correct versions.